# UIView doesn't sizeToFit if a method is called by its self

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created a method
`- (UIView *) drawView:(NSMutableArray *) arrayToDisplay;`
which works perfectly if it is called by another method, e.g.
`-(void) preperationsBeforeDrawView`.
But inside of `arrayToDisplay` I have a loop which gets activated if it finds a special object.

```objectivec
- (UIView *) drawView:(NSMutableArray *) arrayToDisplay {

[UIView * overAllView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

 while ([arrayToDisplay containsObject:myObject]) {

     NSMutableArray *subArray = [[arrayToDisplay subarrayWithRange:NSRange] mutableCopy];
     UIView *result = [self drawView:subArray];
     [overAllView addSubView:result];
}
/* 

* All the others drawView things

* Create Labels & Views

* add them as subview

*/
[overAllView sizeToFit];
return overAllView;
}
```

So, if the while-Loop is calling `[self drawView:subArray]` the returned UIView doesn't sizeToFit, even if it has subViews which have (width, height != 0). It doesn't show any effect no matter if I call sizeToFit inside `drawView` or after. But the returned UIView from the first called `drawView` works perfectly.

Can you please tell me where I made the mistake?

Comment: There are a few syntax errors in this code, like the left brace on the third line, and the NSRange on the 7th line needs to be replaced with an actual NSMakeRange(,) call.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're going to get sizeToFit to work. It's probably better and clearer to calculate the required frame from the subviews and their positions.

Comment: The code is just a place holder. The original one has 50 lines of code and works perfectly, if called first time from outside.

Comment: If sizeToFit does not seem to work quite the way you like, you might be able to override - (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size in a subclass of UIView, that should cause sizeToFit to do what you want. At least it's what the documentation on those two methods said will happen for that subclass of UIView. https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622625-sizethatfits?language=objc

Comment: Is it possible that subArray contains the special myObject ?

Comment: @simple_code Yes.

Comment: Maybe that's part of the problem? Does it draw correctly if subArray does not contain myObject?

Comment: Yes. But myObject doesn't get draw. It just says create a subArray from here to there and take me out.